# django dictionaries for model method results

Tags: django, python-2.7

For these models:

```
class Publisher(models.Model):      
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    code = models.SmallIntegerField(unique=True)

class Book(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    hardback = models.BooleanField()
    large_print = models.BooleanField()
    foreign_lang = models.BooleanField()
```

For each boolean field, I want to have the Publisher sorted by percentage of that field, and total book count.

Eg

#### Large Print

Publisher - Percentage Large Print - Total Books

I've got model methods Publisher.get_percentage and Publisher.total_count that calculates these when supplied with a date range (d1, d2) and the relevant boolean field (choice).

d1 and d2 will be selected by the user from a form.

I'm working on a view like this:

```
def data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            choices = ['publisher__hardback','publisher__large_print','publisher__foreign_lang']
            for choice in choices:
                ch = {}
                pub = Publisher.objects.all()
                for p in pub:
                    ch = {p.code : p.total_count : p.get_percentage(cd.d1, cd.d2, choice)}
```

What's the best way to create a new dictionary for each choice, and append the values to the dictionary ?

I think I need to create these dictionaries in the view (rather than just iterating through the publishers in a template) as I want to order the results by percentage...

Is there a better way to achieve all of this ?!

Thanks

Comment: You're writing too much code. Find a query that does what you want instead (Hint: Aggregation).

Comment: You mean like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201482/incremental-count-and-calculation-in-django-model ?